# Drupal 8.2.0 Commerce 2.x installation failed

Tags: drupal-8, commerce

Installing Drupal Commerce 2.x modules by executing the following drupal command

```
drupal module:install commerce_product commerce_checkout commerce_cart commerce_tax
```

generates the following error

```
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "module:install" is not defined.
  Did you mean one of these?
      site:install
      module:download
```

By trying

```
drupal module:download commerce_product commerce_checkout commerce_cart commerce_tax
```

generates the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Drupal\Console\Command\drupal_static_reset() in C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drupal\console\src\Command\ProjectDownloadTrait.php:55
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drupal\console\src\Command\Module\DownloadCommand.php(64): Drupal\Console\Command\Module\DownloadCommand->downloadModules(Object(Drupal\Console\Style\DrupalStyle), Array, false)
#1 C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(259): Drupal\Console\Command\Module\DownloadCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Drupal\Console\Style\DrupalStyle))
#2 C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(863): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Drupal\Console\Style\DrupalStyle))
#3 C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(192): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun in C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drupal\console\src\Command\ProjectDownloadTrait.php on line 55
```

Any idea about how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this: `drush en commerce` after Would you like to download them? (y/n): y, and it will download it for you.
Hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can install easily with composer:

```
cd /path/to/drupal8
composer require "drupal/<modulename>:<version>"
```

Or without version:

```
composer require "drupal/<modulename>"
```

For example:

```
composer require "drupal/commerce_product"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to this :

`composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction`

It's explained here in the README.md : 
https://github.com/drupalcommerce/project-base/blob/8.x/README.md